# How to prevent a table from overflowing its enclosing div on resize?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, smart-table

I have a table defined using bootstrap 3 and some custom css. When I resize the browser window it ends overflowing the table beyond the width of the enclosing div as shown in the picture below. I am using IE and the developers tool shows no computed table attribute affecting this behavior. I also checked the `tr` and `td` dynamically computed attributes and still no luck finding the culprit for this behavior.

[image: table overflows enclosing div]

Can anyone shed some light into what settings could be provoking this?

```
<div class="pad-top pad-side">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default" ng-show="{{reportData.PnlStatistics != undefined}}" style="height: 380px">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <label>Expected In-Sample PnL Statistics</label>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                    <table class="table table-x-condensed table-striped table-hover table_nowrap" id="pnlStatisticsTable" st-safe-src="pnlStatistics"
                           st-table="displayedPnlStatistics">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 60%;" id="name">Name</th>
                                <th style="width: 20%;" id="daily">Daily</th>
                                <th style="width: 20%;" id="optimal">Optimal</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="data in displayedPnlStatistics">
                                <td style="width: 60%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">{{data.name}}</td>
                                <td style="width: 20%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">{{data.DailyHedge}}</td>
                                <td style="width: 20%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">{{data.OptimalHedge}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use media queries to implicitly adjust the width of the table on smaller viewports.

Comment: At what screen size does this start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found was to modify the enclosing `div` style and set a minimum width. This prevents the enclosing parent `div` from shrinking below the contents size and it works great.

```
<div class="col-lg-3" style="min-width: 350px;">
    ...
</div>
```